# LESS "-webkit-gradient" not correctly compiled

Tags: css, laravel, less

I wrote these in a LESS file and compile it with gulp in Laravel Elixir. The `background-image` attribute didn't exist in the css file gulp generated. However, other attributes like `margin-bottom` exist.

```
.navbar {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f8f8f8), to(#EAE6E6));
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I didn't receive any error message, How to check the error log?

**Laravel 5.0**

Comment: The `webkit-gradient` syntax is a pretty old one and I think it has been more than 2 years since Webkit moved to the `-webkit-linear-gradient` (and then to `linear-gradient`). Are you sure you need it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/why-does-laravel-elixir-with-gulp-remove-some-of-my-css)

You can just write the standard syntax and the LESS autoprefixer can add prefix when compiling.

It's a elixir feature-issue and I didn't know it....   Hope Laravel's document will point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#eae6e6 100%)
```

Comment: The from and to syntax does compile correctly in the latest Less compiler and if I remember right, old webkit gradient syntax did have it.

Comment: No, still not exist, I didn't receive error message, but the attribute still not in the css file generated.

Comment: OK, you are right. I changed my answer, and the above does compile using npm's lessc.

Comment: @HelloWorld  I post my own answer, thank you anyway.